# How to print the sign %?

Tags: scala

How do I print the sign `%` in the following string?

```
println("%s : %d".format("percent", 100))
```

I need to get

```
percent: 100%
```

If I do `println("%s : %d%".format("percent", 100))`, the program fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the `%` with `%%`:

```
@ println("%s : %d%%".format("percent", 100))
percent : 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

why can't you use string interpolation? like this:

```
val x = 100
  println(s"percent: $x%")
```